# x-ray vertex shader opengl es 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es

I found [this vertex shader](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~rich/courses/imgd4000-d10/homework/xray.vert):

```
// Application to vertex shader
varying vec3 N;
varying vec3 I;
varying vec4 Cs;

void main()
{
    vec4 P = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    I  = P.xyz - vec3 (0);
    N  = gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal;
    Cs = gl_Color;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

This shader works with my 3D model I am running on OSX. However, I am trying to get the same model running for openFrameworks and openGL ES 2.0 for Android. My 3D model is loading properly, and my fragment shader seems to be compiling properly for openGL ES 2.0. However, my vertex shader will not compile. Does anyone know how I can change this code so it will run on Android?

**This is what I see in LogCat:**

```
08-29 13:47:24.499: V/ofShader(26349): checkAndCreateProgram(): creating GLSL program

08-29 13:47:24.499: E/ofShader(26349): setupShaderFromSource(): GL_VERTEX_SHADER shader failed to compile

08-29 13:47:24.499: E/(26349): ofShader: GL_VERTEX_SHADER shader reports:

08-29 13:47:24.499: E/(26349): Vertex shader compilation failed.

08-29 13:47:24.499: E/(26349): ERROR: 0:8: 'gl_ModelViewMatrix' : undeclared identifier 

08-29 13:47:24.499: E/(26349): ERROR: 0:8: 'gl_Vertex' : undeclared identifier 

08-29 13:47:24.499: E/(26349): ERROR: 0:8: '=' :  cannot convert from 'float' to '4-component vector of float'

08-29 13:47:24.499: E/(26349): ERROR: 0:10: 'gl_NormalMatrix' : undeclared identifier 

08-29 13:47:24.499: E/(26349): ERROR: 0:10: 'gl_Normal' : undeclared identifier 

08-29 13:47:24.499: E/(26349): ERROR: 0:10: 'assign' :  cannot convert from 'float' to 'varying 3-component vector of float'

08-29 13:47:24.499: E/(26349): ERROR: 0:11: 'gl_Color' : undeclared identifier 

08-29 13:47:24.499: E/(26349): ERROR: 0:11: 'assign' :  cannot convert from 'float' to 'varying 4-component vector of float'

08-29 13:47:24.499: E/(26349): ERROR: 0:12: 'gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix' : undeclared identifier 

08-29 13:47:24.499: E/(26349): ERROR: 0:12: 'assign' :  cannot convert from 'float' to 'Position 4-component vector of float'

08-29 13:47:24.499: E/(26349): ERROR: 10 compilation errors.  No code generated.

08-29 13:47:24.499: V/ofShader(26349): setupShaderFromSource(): GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER shader compiled

08-29 13:47:24.499: V/(26349): linkProgram(): attaching GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER shader to program 22

08-29 13:47:24.499: E/ofShader(26349): checkProgramLinkStatus(): program failed to link
```

Comment: What error are you seeing in the GL log?

Comment: I edited the post to include the LogCat output; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
vec4 P = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^ nope
I  = P.xyz - vec3 (0);
N  = gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal;
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^ nope
Cs = gl_Color;
     ^^^^^^^^ nope
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^ nope
```

ES 2.0 doesn't provide those built-ins.  You'll have to supply/calculate them yourself using generic uniforms/attributes.

ES 2.0 only provides two built-in variables in the vertex shader stage:

```
highp vec4 gl_Position; // should be written to
mediump float gl_PointSize; // may be written to
```

See the [GLSL ES 1.0 spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf), section 7.1, page 59.